# Error al Descargar un archivo Excel con data desde .Net y C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web, descarga

El problema es el siguiente, estoy generando un archivo mediante unos datos enviados como lista desde `C#` en `Javascript`.

```
ExcelRangeBase celdas = null;
      
celdas = wsData.Cells[CeldaOrigen].LoadFromCollection(Data, false);
```

Con esta Librería ejecuta el sistema y `Wsdata` es una plantilla para ejecutar `Excel`.

Cuando me voy a dar cuenta en un archivo Temporal del `API`, lo genera perfectamente, pero al descargarlo desde `javascript` se coloca los datos encima del de la primera fila en donde esta el nombre de la Columna.

No entiendo si le estoy enviando la fila la cual quiero que se ejecute la data, no se si me puedan ayudar.

Aquí muestro una imagen de como se muestra al descargar

[image: como se muestra al descargar]

Debería salirme de la siguiente manera:

[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: déjame adivinar, usas epplus?.